# Stored Procedure to check if username exists in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, stored-procedures

I need user to enter the username in a web form in asp.net. When the user enters and clicks a button I need the label to display if username exists in particular database or not. I have tried executing a stored procedure but it always shows the message "username found" though I have given the username which is not in that database.

Here is my stored procedure

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCheckUsernameForAnswer]
  @userName varchar(20)
  as
  begin
  Declare @count int
       select @count=COUNT(username) from UpdatedAnswer where [username] =@userName 
   if(@count=1)
    Begin
    Select 1 as ReturnCode
    End
      Else
         Begin
         Select -1 as Returncode
        End
  End
  GO
```

Below is my code behind file which gets executed on button click

```
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCheckUsernameForAnswer", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter parausername = new SqlParameter("@username", GetUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parausername);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["ReturnCode"]))
                {
                    ErrorUserLabel.Text = "Username found";

                }
                else
                {
                    ErrorUserLabel.Text = "not found";
                }
            }

        }
```

I can guess problem resides in this code behind but I don't know how to resolve it.!! Please help I am a newbie in .net !! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that both 1 and -1 are resolving to true in Convert.ToBoolean. Try returning 0 rather than -1 if the username isn't found, or check for greater than or less than 0 in the code behind instead of converting to a boolean.

Comment: Wow !! It worked ..Thanks a lot.. I changed Select -1 to 0 and it worked @Chris Flynn